# Karaf loading OSGI bundle error Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: xml, osgi, apache-karaf

I am trying to get a sample OSGI bundle deployed to my local maven repo loaded in Karaf and getting the error

```
karaf@root> features:addurl mvn:io.spray/on-karaf/1.2-M8
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Error executing command: Unable to add repositories:
    Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Here's my `features.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<features xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.2.0" name="io.spray.examples.karaf">
    <feature name="io.spray.examples.karaf" version="1.2-M8">
        <bundle>mvn:io.spray/on-karaf/1.2-M8</bundle>

        <bundle>mvn:com.typesafe.akka/akka-osgi_2.10/2.2.0-RC2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.typesafe/config/1.0.1</bundle>
        <bundle>wrap:mvn:com.chuusai/shapeless_2.10.0-RC5/1.2.3</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.parboiled/parboiled-core/1.1.5</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.parboiled/parboiled-scala_2.10/1.1.5</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.0</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.10.0</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:io.spray/spray-util/1.2-M8</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru/1.3.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:io.spray/spray-caching/1.2-M8</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:io.spray/spray-http/1.2-M8</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:io.spray/spray-io/1.2-M8</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:io.spray/spray-can/1.2-M8</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.jvnet.mimepull/mimepull/1.9.2</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:io.spray/spray-httpx/1.2-M8</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:io.spray/spray-routing/1.2-M8</bundle>

        <bundle>wrap:mvn:io.spray/spray-json/1.2.5</bundle>
    </feature>
</features>
```

Here's the `MANIFEST.MF`

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Vendor: io.spray
Implementation-Title: on-karaf
Implementation-Version: 1.2-M8
Implementation-Vendor-Id: io.spray
Specification-Vendor: io.spray
Specification-Title: on-karaf
Implementation-URL: http://spray.io
Specification-Version: 1.2-M8
```

I think my `MANIFEST.MF` might be incorrect, could this be the cause? I am new to Karaf, OSGI, and maven, so it's possible I missed an important step.

Comment: This is an XML processing error, but I'm not sure what's wrong with the XML. Maybe the `standalone="yes"` part?

Comment: Has to be your XML file or some other XML file with some strange characters/encoding in the beginning. Open it with some editor that is able to show HEX and trouble shoot.

Comment: @NeilBartlett @Petter yeah that's my thinking too but I was able to run `xmllint` on it just fine, so not sure what could be the issue. Does `MANIFEST.MF` looks correct to you though?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the manifest, but that's irrelevant. The error message is from the XML parser, I'm certain of that. I think that @SheenaArtrip's answer is the most likely to be right... you're trying to process a JAR file as if it were an XML file.

Answer (score 1):

The features:addUrl line is wrong. *mvn:io.spray/on-karaf/1.2-M8* points to a JAR, so using addurl on it will try to parse the jar file as if it was XML. If your feature.xml is within a JAR file, you must reference the XML directly:

```
features:addurl mvn:io.spray/on-karaf/1.2-M8/xml/features
```

http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.2/deploy_osgi/DeployFeatures-Create.html

Comment: That didn't work for me, got `Error executing command: Unable to add repositories:
 URL [mvn:io.spray/on-karaf/1.2-M8/xml/features] could not be resolved.`

Comment: Can you show the contents of the JAR on io.spray/on-karaf/1.2-M8? If it won't resolve, it means your features XML file may not be in the file OR it may be in a different location in the file. 

You may also want to ensure that the mvn: protocol handler is even looking in your local maven folder and not just looking in the remote server.

EDIT: looks like your answer comment below says that you are finding the actual jar (because 'cat' gives you a JAR binary) but you aren't finding the features.xml in your JAR.

Comment: `features.xml` with the contents as shown above is at the root level, `META-INF/MANIFEST.XML`, bunch of classes in `examples` folder.

Comment: That is all I have, then. Best bet might be to refer to the XML directly, with a file: uri, to best isolate the problem.

The standard karaf features xml is deployed alongside the JAR file as well as being inside the jar file. Not sure which one addurl uses, actually. 

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/karaf/assemblies/features/standard/2.3.1/

Answer (score 0):

I had this error once when I was at a conference. The problem was that the wlan router there required authentication using a web form. I turned on the wlan but was not authenticated. So for every url the form came back.

When adding the feature or installing bundles this can result in invalid content being used.
In my case it was even worst as maven was caching some of the invalid content in the maven repo. So I had to delete these files even after my wlan was working again.

You can check if this problem happened to you by doing a cat on the feature url in the maven console:

cat mvn:io.spray/on-karaf/1.2-M8

Comment: That isn't an issue for me it seems, I saw a binary dump of sorts, here's a snippet of the first couple of lines `F??BMETA-INF/MANIFEST.MF???M??LK-.?
K-*??ϳR0?3????-?I?M?+I,`

Comment: The feature file should not be a jar file. Are you perhaps using the wrong maven uri?

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup your project packaging to `pom` instead of (the default) `jar`, such that the resources get placed in the repository directly, and not within a jar. Add
`<packaging>pom</packaging>` to your maven pom, redeploy and you should be fine. (In Karaf, execute `features:addurl mvn:io.spray/on-karaf/1.2-M8/xml/features`.) That did the trick for me at least.